# How do I get around the problem Package xkeyval Error: `minibox' undefined in `adjbox, Gin, adjcalc'?

Tags: pdftex

I am writing problem solving tips for students, and I want to put the hints in a column, with examples in the right margin and some anecdotal notes in the left margin. I want the left margin text orientation rotated. My example below works without text rotation. When I put in text rotation I get the xkeyval error. My search has not helped to resolve my problem.
Is what am trying to do possible. I added so many packages, some of which am sure are not necessary. Below my MWE.
Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,oneside]{memoir}
\isopage[6] % Quick and dirty large margins
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage{xkeyval} % \RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
          a4paper,
          total={210mm,297mm},
          left=40mm,
          right=60mm,
          top=20mm,
          bottom=15mm,
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-1.5in}
\centering
\vspace{1in}
\Huge Problem Solving Tips \\
\vspace{0.1in}
in Matrix Operations\\
and Elementary Linear Algebra

\normalsize
\vspace{1in}
 \Large Zilore Mumba
\vspace{5in}
\today
\vspace{1in}
\end{adjustwidth}
\break
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Basic Matrix Operations}
The basic matrix operations which the student must be proficient in are: matrix
addition scalar and multiplication,

{\begin{adjustbox}{minibox=\textwidth,angle=180}
\sidepar{
The word matrix is late Latin for womb; it is the same root as
maternal or matrimony. The idea being that a matrix is a receptacle
for holding numbers. \\

}}
\end{adjustbox}
\marginpar{
Many abstract objects which will be encountered in various topics of linear algebra, such as "change of basis", "linear transformations","bilinear forms", etc can conveniently be represented by matrices.
}
matrixmultiplication and elementary row
and column operations. These operations are straight forward, General  tips:

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `minibox` key; and `adjustbox` should be *inside* `\sidepar`, not outside.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Basic Matrix Operations}
The basic matrix operations which the student must be proficient in are: matrix
addition scalar and multiplication,

\sidepar{%
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,angle=180}
  \raggedright
  The word matrix is late Latin for womb; it is the same root as
  maternal or matrimony. The idea being that a matrix is a receptacle
  for holding numbers.
  \end{adjustbox}
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not sure what the rotation is for.

Comment: Thanks very much @egreg, you have really solved my problem which I have been on for days. The rotation is actually 90 degrees so that text orientation is vertical, but I will also use 180 for solutions. The only problem I have now is to locate the text in the right position, which I will now work on. Thanks for your time and effort.